# How can I display the the highest value of three floats using a another string?

Tags: c++

I want to display the item name of the highest value of all three item Prices
  if item1Price was the highest value it would display item1Name like this
  So it would say 'You should swap "apples" for something less expensive'

```
string item1Name;
string item2Name;
string item3Name;

float item1Price;
float item2Price;
float item3Price;
float budget;
float total;

cout<<"Please input your budget: ";
cin>>budget;


cout<<"Please input the first items name: ";
cin>>item1Name;

cout<<"Please input the second items name: ";
cin>>item2Name;

cout<<"Please input the third items name: ";
cin>>item3Name;


cout<<"Please input the first items price: ";
cin>>item1Price;

cout<<"Please input the second items price: ";
cin>>item2Price;

cout<<"Please input third items price: "
cin>>item3Price;


system("CLS");


total = item1Price + item2Price + item3Price;

cout<<"the total cost is "<<total<<endl;

if(total > budget)
{
    cout<<"you have gone overbudget!"<<endl;

    cout<<"Maybe you could swap "<< //most expensive item goes here;
}
```

Comment: Try using `std::max` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/

Comment: Use an array for both, find the index of the largest price and use it to retrieve its name (assuming you can't make a `item` class with name and price attributes).

Comment: cout<<"you have gone overbudget!"<<endl;
  std::max(item1Price, item2Price, item3Price) = hValue;
  cout<<"Maybe you could swap "<<hValue<<" for something less expensive";

Comment: I have done this but it says hValue was not declared in this scope

Comment: @streamfire your code makes no sense, computers are fussy, you can't just make stuff up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (item1Price > item2Price && item1Price > item3Price)
    cout << "you should swap " << item1Name << " for something less expensive\n";
```

etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
void main()
{
string item1Name;
string item2Name;
string item3Name;

float item1Price;
float item2Price;
float item3Price;
float budget;
float total;

cout<<"Please input your budget: ";
cin>>budget;


cout<<"Please input the first items name: ";
cin>>item1Name;

cout<<"Please input the second items name: ";
cin>>item2Name;

cout<<"Please input the third items name: ";
cin>>item3Name;


cout<<"Please input the first items price: ";
cin>>item1Price;

cout<<"Please input the second items price: ";
cin>>item2Price;

cout<<"Please input third items price: "
cin>>item3Price;


system("CLS");


total = item1Price + item2Price + item3Price;

cout<<"the total cost is "<<total<<endl;
if (item1Price < item2Price  item1Price < item3Price)
{
  if(item2Price>item3Price)
  {
  cout<<"you should swap " << item2Name << " for something less     expensive\n";
}
else
{
cout<<"you should swap " << item3Name << " for something less expensive\n";
}

}
else
{
cout<<"you should swap " << item1Name << " for something less expensive\n";
}


if(total > budget)
{
    cout<<"you have gone overbudget!"<<endl;

    cout<<"Maybe you could swap "<< //most expensive item goes here;
}
}
```